# Default template for a content type defined in an orchard module

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I'm creating a Product content type in a custom Orchard module.  I'd like to define the default template to use for rending Product content items in my module.  Clients using my module should then be able to override my default template in their own themes.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Read this: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates

Comment: Thanks Bertrand.  I had seen that page.  It does seem to indicate that I can define content item templates in my module.  However, it's not working for me.  I added the following file to my module: Views\Items\Content.Product.cshtml.  But the default content template is still used.  When I use shape tracing to view the available alternates, it only lists paths that are relative to my active theme.  That got me wondering if it's really possible to provide a per content type template in my module.

Comment: I was doing something wrong!  The template path should have been: Views\Items\Content-Product.cshtml